# Is it possible to disable "Try it" functionality on API Management Developer Portal?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I'm working to customize APIM Dev Portal and I dont want allow user use 'Try it' functionality so How to disable it ?

Comment: Maybe self host it?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-self-host

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way of doing that, either create a custom widget to hid it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-extend-custom-functionality#create-and-upload-custom-widget or self host the portal and customize it the way you want